# Keep application alive while debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I have an application running on a real device. I am telling it to wait for the debug hook:

```
adb shell am set-debug-app -w my.app.name
```

Then, I click "Attach debugger to Android process" from Android Studio.

Debugging starts successfully and my breakpoint is hit.

However, after around 20 seconds, the application is killed on the device and my debug session is terminated.

Is there a way of keeping the application alive such that I can continue debugging?

Otherwise, if the application can not be kept alive, is there a way to keep stepping through in the debug process even though the application is killed?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clicking the "Debug app"[image: spider icon with the play button] button next to the instant run button? It automatically installs a build with the debugger attached.

On a side note, your  app seems to be crashing. Have you tried looking in the logcat ?

Comment: The "Debug App" fails with `Error running YourApp. Default activity not found`. This is because my app doesn't have an `intent-filter` under an `activity`, just under a `receiver`. The app isn't crashing, it just gets removed because of inactivity. That's how it's supposed to work.

Comment: could you paste some code of your Manifest and BroadcastReceiver?